# Lebesgue outer measure, real analysis

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $E$ have finite outer measure. Show that $E$ is measurable if and only if for each open, bounded interval $(a,b)$,

$(b-a)=m^*((a,b) \cap E)+ m^* ((a,b) \cap E^c)$.

The forward direction (assuming $E$ is measurable) follows directly from the definition. But I can't figure out how to show the backward way.